# Blackberry Java Tabs in BB 7.0

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, tabs

I cant find **ANY** examples of using the `HorizontalTabTitleView` class.

Ive tried many things of which the below should work! But it comes up blank.

The created Hierachy is:

`HorizontalTabTitleView -> PaneManagerModel -> Pane -> VerticalFieldManager-> BasicEditField`

Where PaneManagerModel can hold Many Panes which are used as Tabs.

```
    HorizontalTabTitleView tabView = new HorizontalTabTitleView(VERTICAL_SCROLL );

    tab1 = new LabelField("Page 1");


    BasicEditField Name = new BasicEditField( "Name:", "", 100, BasicEditField.EDITABLE );
    tab1Manager = new VerticalFieldManager();
    tab1Manager.add( Name ); 

    PaneManagerModel pneMger = new PaneManagerModel();
    Pane pne1 = new Pane(tab1, tab1Manager );

    pneMger.addPane(pne1);

    tabView.setModel(pneMger);
    //tabView.setNumberOfDisplayedTabs(3);
    add(tabView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on [on Blackberry support pages](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-with-tab-pane-appearance/td-p/1354299) had a problem on making a transparent tab providing a working example of the usage of `HorizontalTabTitleView` on the code part of his question. The question maker at least says that his code is working (despite the transparency), so would you like to have look? =)

Comment: Excellent find. Looking briefly at it, it looks very promising. I will try it on Monday and let you know how it goes ;). Thanks.

Comment: Yea it works great. I was missing some kind of `HorizontalTabController` and `PaneManagerView`. Thanks a lot ;)